# Show that there exists $x_0$ such that $p(x_0) < q(x_0)$ for the given polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots

> If $p(x) = x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and $q(x) = x^2+px+q$ be two polynomials with real coefficients. Suppose that there exists an interval $(r,s)$ of length greater than 2 such that both $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are negative for $x \in (r,s)$ and both are positive for $x<r$ or $x>s$. Show that there exists $x_0$ such that $p(x_0) < q(x_0)$

Since $q(x)$ is a quadratic, therefore $r$ and $s$ have to be the roots.

but, $r$ and $s$ are also the roots of $p(x)$ so, $q(x)$ has to be a factor of $p(x)$, therefore

$p(x) = q(x)g(x)$

Where $g(x)$ is also a quadratic. But that's as far as I could get. How do proceed from here? How do you make use of the condition $s-r > 2$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Tony Yes, $|r-s| \gt 2$ is key to proving it. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Tony As I cannot write a comment on your erased question, I write it here. I have understood why your approach couldn't be successful : by writing $(2n+1)x=k \pi$, for any $k$, you don't express the fact that $k$ is constrained to take only a certain set of values.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for your time jean. But I figured out that I went wrong in simplifying the expression after taking cot on both sides. I had also restricted the values of k ( 1<k<n) but I forgot to mention it in my answer. So yeah, that was a stupid question that deserved to get deleted. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Tony No question is stupid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r$ and $s$ are roots of both $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ and hence it is also the root of $p(x) - q(x)$.

$q(x) = (x-r)(x-s)$ where $|r - s| \gt 2$

$p(x) - q(x) = q(x)f(x)$

**Let's assume $p(x) - q(x)$ is always non-negative but given its roots are $r$ and $s$, it is only possible if $f(x)$ is negative whenever $q(x)$ is and $f(x)$ is positive whenever $q(x)$ is.**

That means it has double roots at $r$ and $s$ i.e. $p(x) - q(x) = (x-r)^2(x-s)^2$

i.e. $p(x) - q(x) = q(x)^2$

i.e. $p(x) = q(x)(q(x)+1)$

i.e. $1+q(x) \gt 0$ as $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ have the same sign at all $x$.

i.e. $x^2-(r+s)x+(rs+1) \gt 0$

This cannot be true as its discriminant $(r-s)^2 - 4 \gt 0$ as given in the problem. So there is a value of x where $p(x) \lt q(x)$.

[Note: function $ax^2+bx+c$ has two real roots if its discriminant $b^2-4ac \gt 0$]